# How can I show one colored line at the top of one page only instead the whole website?

Tags: css

I am using this snippet to get a line above the header that shows on all of my pages. I use wordpress.

```
/* line at the top */

body, body.fixed_width {
border-top: 4px solid #000;
}
```

I want to show this at the top of one page only or lets say on the top of the home page only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this

```
body.fixed_width {
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
}
```

It will show only in that page where you use .fixed_width class in a body tag

Comment: How to add it to a body tag?
Do I add this to functions.php? like this: http://my.studiopress.com/snippets/custom-body-class/ if not, I would be glad if you guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Most themes put the body of the home page in a class called `home`.

Try this:

```
body.home, body.fixed_width.home {
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: @sam That's a lot more difficult and depends on specific situations. Try ading the CSS to a file that is loaded only on that page, or perhaps using a selector that selects only something on that page. Without seeing your code, I can't give you a simple answer.